# C#: How would I filter out the unneeded namespaces in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

This is more of a language-agnostic question than a C#-specific one, but since it deals with namespaces I thought I'd tag this as .NET-related.

Say you have a bunch of strings that represent namespaces:

```
[
    "System",
    "System.Windows",
    "System.Windows.Input",
    "System.Windows.Converters",
    "System.Windows.Markup",
    "System.Windows.Markup.Primitives",
    "System.IO",
    "System.IO.Packaging"
]
```

You want to filter them in such a way that any namespace that 'contains' another namespace in the collection is excluded. For example, since `System` contains `System.Windows`, it's excluded. Since `System.IO` is a parent of `System.IO.Packaging`, it's likewise excluded. This continues until you end up with this:

```
[
    "System.Windows.Input",
    "System.Windows.Converters",
    "System.Windows.Markup.Primitives",
    "System.IO.Packaging"
]
```

What would be an efficient way to filter a list this way in C#? I'm looking for a method that will look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> FilterNamespaces(IEnumerable<string> namespaces) {}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

---

**EDIT:** Here is what ultimately worked for me:

```
public IEnumerable<string> FilterNamespaces(IEnumerable<string> namespaces) =>
    namespaces.Where(current => !namespaces.Any(n => n.StartsWith($"{current}.")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> FilterNamespaces(IEnumerable<string> namespaces)
 => namespaces
  .Where(ns => namespaces
    .Where(n => n != ns)
      .All(n => !Regex.IsMatch(n, $@"{Regex.Escape(ns)}[\.\n]")))
  .Distinct();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Wouldn't that malfunction for namespaces like `Sys` and `System` though? `System` starts with `Sys`, but they're not related.

Comment: It is really nice. It is working fine. But there is one problem if there are two packages with the same name say (System.IO.Packaging). It will return both. But you can fix this by calling Distinct on the result.

Comment: tchelidze: Excuse me if I'm being ignorant, but couldn't the dots in the namespace also cause problems if they're inserted in the regex? (since `.` is a special character)

Comment: @BewarSalah Right, simple solution is to place `Distinct()` at the end of a query.

Comment: @JamesKo Sorry james, i can not reproduce what you mean, can you provide an example ?

Comment: tchelidze: Something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOl8vZ) would return true, since `.` matches a single character in regex. You would have to somehow escape the dot.

Comment: @JamesKo James, if i get you question, you mean that since `.` match any (not almost any) character in regex it needs to be escaped, but in the regex above it is actually escaped like this `\.`

Comment: tchelidze: Never mind, I've edited your answer so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @JamesKo Thanks james, now i get what you were telling me. (dot was problem in `ns` not in plain regex.)

Answer (score 3):

You can build a tree where the root is the `System` namespace and every edge will represent a parent-child relation between different namespaces. Then you can find all of the leafs of the tree with a traversing algorithm which finds the rank of every node(nodes with rank=1 are leafs-they do not have children).