# What is the PowerShell equivalent of LINQ's All()?

Tags: linq, powershell

I'm trying to test if a condition is true for all items in an array in PowerShell (similarly to LINQ's `All` function). What would be the 'proper' way to do this in PowerShell, short of writing a manual for-loop?

To be specific, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258044/4077294) is the code I'm trying to translate from C#:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FilterNamespaces(IEnumerable<string> namespaces)
  => namespaces
     .Where(ns => namespaces
       .Where(n => n != ns)
         .All(n => !Regex.IsMatch(n, $@"{Regex.Escape(ns)}[\.\n]")))
     .Distinct();
```

Comment: @Matt Hm, interesting idea. So then something like this: `$filtered = $array -Match $pred; if ($filtered.Length -eq $array.Length)`?

Comment: Not seeing what those variables are... in theory yes.

Comment: Could you please post an example of the item you are testing for the True/False condition?

Comment: While it's somewhat incidental to the question, it helps to understand what this code does: from a list of namespaces, it returns only the ones with the _longest_ path among those sharing a parent path;
e.g., if both `System.Windows` and `System.Windows.Input` are present, only `System.Windows.Input` is returned. I'm confused by the `\n` in the regex, however - wouldn't just `\.` at the end do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't recreate the C#-code in powershell, but rather do it the PowerShell-way. Ex:

```
function Filter-Namespaces ([string[]]$Namespaces) {
  $Namespaces | Where-Object {
    $thisNamespace = $_;
    (
      $Namespaces | ForEach-Object { $_ -match "^$([regex]::Escape($thisNamespace))\." }
    ) -notcontains $true
  } | Select-Object -Unique
}

Filter-Namespaces -Namespaces $values

System.Windows.Input
System.Windows.Converters
System.Windows.Markup.Primitives
System.IO.Packaging
```

However, to answer your question, you could do it the manual way:

```
$values = "System",
"System.Windows",
"System.Windows.Input",
"System.Windows.Converters",
"System.Windows.Markup",
"System.Windows.Markup.Primitives",
"System.IO",
"System.IO.Packaging"

($values | ForEach-Object { $_ -match 'System' }) -notcontains $false

True
```

Or you could create a function for it:

```
function Test-All {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Condition,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    $InputObject
    )

    begin { $result = $true }
    process {
        $InputObject | Foreach-Object { 
            if (-not (& $Condition)) { $result = $false }
        }
    }
    end { $result }
}

$values = "System",
"System.Windows",
"System.Windows.Input",
"System.Windows.Converters",
"System.Windows.Markup",
"System.Windows.Markup.Primitives",
"System.IO",
"System.IO.Packaging"

#Using pipeline
$values | Test-All { $_ -match 'System' }

#Using array arguemtn
Test-All -Condition { $_ -match 'System' } -InputObject $values
#Using single value argument
Test-All -Condition { $_ -match 'System' } -InputObject $values[0]
```

Or you could compile the C# code or load an already compiled dll using `Add-Type`.

Comment: This is a much more sophisticated version of what I was thinking. Slow day for me it seems.

Comment: @Matt, I might have copied the function from my personal module. The "manual way" was real-time though. :)

Comment: The `$InputObject` should be removed from `& $Condition $InputObject`, as this gives the impression that it was passed as an argument to the script block. This would only work if there was an argument defined in the script block itself, e.g. `{ param($Arg) $Arg -match 'System' }`.
The reason the example works anyway is that the automatic variable `$_` happens to hold the same value as `$InputObject` in the process block.

Comment: @lujomu, Wow, this is an old one. :-) There probably was some thought about it that got lost in a rewrite - don't remember anymore, but I've updated the PoC to support both pipeline and arugment-input.