# Filter ArrayList on nested property

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have an PowerShell `ArrayList` (`$displayObjects`) which contains:

```
Name  ID  Tags
----  --  ----
Test1 123 {@{id=4567; name=test1;}}
Test2 345 {@{id=4567; name=test1;}, @{id=6789; name=test2}}
Test3 567 {@{id=4567; name=test1;}, @{id=6789; name=test2}, @{id=7890; name=test3}}
```

And another:

```
$filter = @('test1', 'test2')
```

And waht to filter the `$displayObjects` (`Tags.name`) based on the values specified in the `$filter` array.

So in the case above the result should contain only rows 2 and 3 (from `$displayObjects`).

I've strted thinking and testing with `$displayObjects | Where-Object ...` but cant think of a way how to loop in there. Any suggestions?

Comment: To clarify: if `$filter = @('test1','test2','test3')` the result would only contain 1 row (with ID=567)? correct?
Can you provide the sample code for the `$displayObjects`

Comment: What happens if you try `$displayObjects | Where-Object {$_.Tags -contains $filter }`?

Comment: @DanStef correct. And if `$filter = @('test1')` the result shold return all rows.

Comment: @DanStef The syntax for the `-contains` operator is `<list> -contains <value>`, not `<list> -contains <list>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
... | Where-Object {
    $a = @($_.Tags.name)
    ($filter | Where-Object {$a -contains $_}).Count -eq $filter.Count
}
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this with [LINQ](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/high-performance-powershell-linq) ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35258435/1630171)?), but I'm not versed enough in that.

Comment: seems to work this way. Mind explaining the `.Count` bits. Not sure im getting it :)

Comment: @StefanStoichev The nested `Where-Object` returns all elements from `$filter` that are found in `$a`. Only if all elements of `$filter` are found in `$a` the result count is equal to the number of elements in `$filter` (`$filter.Count`).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It might not be the most efficient way, though.

```
$displayObjects | Where-Object { 
    $tags = [string]$_.Tags
    $returnObject = $true
    $filter | foreach {
        if($tags -notlike "*$_*"){
            $returnObject = $false
        }
    }
    $returnObject
}
```